# What is the difference between FlashList vs RecyclerListView in React Native

Tags: react-native, recyclerlistview, flash-list

[FlashList](https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list) and [RecyclerListView](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) both use Recycle approach for rendering Lists, but what is the difference? In which case should I choose FlashList or RecyclerListView? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FlashList is built on top of RecyclerListView. If you look at the `package.json` you can see that it's a [dependency](https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list/blob/main/package.json). Because a big company like shopify decided to create FlashList, I imagine they added extra functionality to the RecyclerListView, with the main one I can think of is the easiness of converting a FlatList to a FlashList